# Tail Recursion in F# : Stack Overflow

Tags: f#, stack-overflow, tail-recursion, continuation-passing, kosaraju-algorithm

I'm trying to implement Kosaraju's algorithm on a large graph
as part of an assignment [MOOC Algo I Stanford on Coursera]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kosaraju%27s_algorithm

The current code works on a small graph, but I'm hitting Stack Overflow during runtime execution.

Despite having read the relevant chapter in Expert in F#, or other available examples on websites and SO, i still don't get how to use continuation to solve this problem

Below is the full code for general purpose, but it will already fail when executing DFSLoop1 and the recursive function DFSsub inside. I think I'm not making the function tail recursive [because of the instructions

```
t<-t+1
G.[n].finishingtime <- t
```

?]

but i don't understand how i can implement the continuation properly.

When considering only the part that fails, DFSLoop1 is taking as argument a graph to which we will apply Depth-First Search. We need to record the finishing time as part of the algo to proceed to the second part of the algo in a second DFS Loop (DFSLoop2) [of course we are failing before that].

```
open System
open System.Collections.Generic
open System.IO

let x = File.ReadAllLines "C:\Users\Fagui\Documents\GitHub\Learning Fsharp\Algo Stanford I\PA 4 - SCC.txt";;
// let x = File.ReadAllLines "C:\Users\Fagui\Documents\GitHub\Learning Fsharp\Algo Stanford I\PA 4 - test1.txt";;
// val x : string [] =

let splitAtTab (text:string)=
    text.Split [|'\t';' '|]

let splitIntoKeyValue (A: int[]) = 
    (A.[0], A.[1])

let parseLine (line:string)=
    line
    |> splitAtTab
    |> Array.filter (fun s -> not(s=""))
    |> Array.map (fun s-> (int s))
    |> splitIntoKeyValue

let y =
    x |> Array.map parseLine
 //val it : (int * int) [] 

type Children = int[]
type Node1 =  
     {children : Children ;
      mutable finishingtime : int ;
      mutable explored1 : bool ; 
      }

type Node2 = 
     {children : Children ;
      mutable leader : int ;
      mutable explored2 : bool ; 
      }

type DFSgraphcore    = Dictionary<int,Children>
let directgraphcore  = new DFSgraphcore()
let reversegraphcore = new DFSgraphcore()

type DFSgraph1    = Dictionary<int,Node1>
let reversegraph1 = new DFSgraph1()

type DFSgraph2    = Dictionary<int,Node2>
let directgraph2  = new DFSgraph2()

let AddtoGraph (G:DFSgraphcore) (n,c) = 
    if not(G.ContainsKey n) then 
                              let node = [|c|]
                              G.Add(n,node)
                            else
                               let c'= G.[n]
                               G.Remove(n) |> ignore
                               G.Add (n, Array.append c' [|c|])

let inline swaptuple (a,b) = (b,a)
y|> Array.iter (AddtoGraph directgraphcore)
y|> Array.map swaptuple |> Array.iter (AddtoGraph reversegraphcore)

for i in directgraphcore.Keys do
    if reversegraphcore.ContainsKey(i) then do

               let node = {children = reversegraphcore.[i] ;
                           finishingtime = -1 ;
                           explored1 = false ;
                           }
               reversegraph1.Add (i,node)

        else                                   
               let node = {children = [||] ;
                           finishingtime = -1 ;
                           explored1 = false ;
                           }
               reversegraph1.Add (i,node)

directgraphcore.Clear  |> ignore
reversegraphcore.Clear |> ignore

// for i in reversegraph1.Keys do printfn "%d %A" i reversegraph1.[i].children
printfn "pause"
Console.ReadKey() |> ignore

let num_nodes =
    directgraphcore |> Seq.length


let DFSLoop1 (G:DFSgraph1)  = 
     let mutable t = 0
     let mutable s = -1
     let mutable k = num_nodes

     let rec DFSsub (G:DFSgraph1)(n:int) (cont:int->int) =
     //how to make it tail recursive ???

          G.[n].explored1 <- true
          // G.[n].leader <- s
          for j in G.[n].children do
                       if not(G.[j].explored1) then DFSsub G j cont
          t<-t+1
          G.[n].finishingtime <- t  

     // end of DFSsub

     for i in num_nodes .. -1 .. 1 do
        printfn "%d" i
        if not(G.[i].explored1) then do 
                                    s <- i
                                    ( DFSsub G i (fun s -> s) ) |> ignore
     //   printfn "%d %d" i G.[i].finishingtime

DFSLoop1 reversegraph1

printfn "pause"
Console.ReadKey() |> ignore

for i in directgraphcore.Keys do
    let node = {children = 
                       directgraphcore.[i]
                       |> Array.map (fun k -> reversegraph1.[k].finishingtime)  ;
                leader = -1 ;
                explored2= false ;
                }
    directgraph2.Add (reversegraph1.[i].finishingtime,node)

let z = 0

let DFSLoop2 (G:DFSgraph2)  = 
     let mutable t = 0
     let mutable s = -1
     let mutable k = num_nodes

     let rec DFSsub (G:DFSgraph2)(n:int) (cont:int->int) =

          G.[n].explored2 <- true
          G.[n].leader <- s
          for j in G.[n].children do
                       if not(G.[j].explored2) then DFSsub G j cont
          t<-t+1
          // G.[n].finishingtime <- t  

     // end of DFSsub

     for i in num_nodes .. -1 .. 1 do
        if not(G.[i].explored2) then do 
                                    s <- i
                                    ( DFSsub G i (fun s -> s) ) |> ignore
       // printfn "%d %d" i G.[i].leader

DFSLoop2 directgraph2

printfn "pause"
Console.ReadKey() |> ignore


let table = [for i in directgraph2.Keys do yield directgraph2.[i].leader]
let results = table |> Seq.countBy id |> Seq.map snd |> Seq.toList |> List.sort |> List.rev
printfn "%A" results

printfn "pause"
Console.ReadKey() |> ignore
```

Here is a text file with a simple graph example

```
1 4
2 8
3 6
4 7
5 2
6 9
7 1
8 5
8 6
9 7
9 3
```

(the one which is causing overflow is 70Mo big with around 900,000 nodes)

**EDIT**

to clarify a few things first
Here is the "pseudo code"

Input: a directed graph G = (V,E), in adjacency list representation. Assume that the vertices V are labeled
1, 2, 3, . . . , n.
1. Let Grev denote the graph G after the orientation of all arcs have been reversed.
2. Run the DFS-Loop subroutine on Grev, processing vertices according to the given order, to obtain a
finishing time f(v) for each vertex v ∈ V .
3. Run the DFS-Loop subroutine on G, processing vertices in decreasing order of f(v), to assign a leader
to each vertex v ∈ V .
4. The strongly connected components of G correspond to vertices of G that share a common leader.
**Figure 2**: The top level of our SCC algorithm. The f-values and leaders are computed in the first and second
calls to DFS-Loop, respectively (see below).

Input: a directed graph G = (V,E), in adjacency list representation.
1. Initialize a global variable t to 0.
[This keeps track of the number of vertices that have been fully explored.]
2. Initialize a global variable s to NULL.
[This keeps track of the vertex from which the last DFS call was invoked.]
3. For i = n downto 1:
[In the first call, vertices are labeled 1, 2, . . . , n arbitrarily. In the second call, vertices are labeled by
their f(v)-values from the first call.]
(a) if i not yet explored:
i. set s := i
ii. DFS(G, i)
**Figure 3**: The DFS-Loop subroutine.

Input: a directed graph G = (V,E), in adjacency list representation, and a source vertex i ∈ V .
1. Mark i as explored.
[It remains explored for the entire duration of the DFS-Loop call.]
2. Set leader(i) := s
3. For each arc (i, j) ∈ G:
(a) if j not yet explored:
i. DFS(G, j)
4. t + +
5. Set f(i) := t
**Figure 4**: The DFS subroutine. The f-values only need to be computed during the first call to DFS-Loop, and
the leader values only need to be computed during the second call to DFS-Loop.

**EDIT**
i have amended the code, with the help of an experienced programmer (a lisper but who has no experience in F#) simplifying somewhat the first part to have more quickly an example without bothering about non-relevant code for this discussion.

The code focuses only on half of the algo, running DFS once to get finishing times of the reversed tree.

This is the first part of the code just to create a small example
y is the original tree. the first element of a tuple is the parent, the second is the child. But we will be working with the reverse tree

```
open System
open System.Collections.Generic
open System.IO

let x = File.ReadAllLines "C:\Users\Fagui\Documents\GitHub\Learning Fsharp\Algo Stanford I\PA 4 - SCC.txt";;
// let x = File.ReadAllLines "C:\Users\Fagui\Documents\GitHub\Learning Fsharp\Algo Stanford I\PA 4 - test1.txt";;
// val x : string [] =

let splitAtTab (text:string)=
    text.Split [|'\t';' '|]

let splitIntoKeyValue (A: int[]) = 
    (A.[0], A.[1])

let parseLine (line:string)=
    line
    |> splitAtTab
    |> Array.filter (fun s -> not(s=""))
    |> Array.map (fun s-> (int s))
    |> splitIntoKeyValue

// let y =
//    x |> Array.map parseLine

//let y =
//   [|(1, 4); (2, 8); (3, 6); (4, 7); (5, 2); (6, 9); (7, 1); (8, 5); (8, 6);
//    (9, 7); (9, 3)|]

// let y = Array.append [|(1,1);(1,2);(2,3);(3,1)|] [|for i in 4 .. 10000 do yield (i,4)|] 
let y = Array.append [|(1,1);(1,2);(2,3);(3,1)|] [|for i in 4 .. 99999 do yield (i,i+1)|] 



 //val it : (int * int) [] 

type Children = int list
type Node1 =  
     {children : Children ;
      mutable finishingtime : int ;
      mutable explored1 : bool ; 
      }

type Node2 = 
     {children : Children ;
      mutable leader : int ;
      mutable explored2 : bool ; 
      }

type DFSgraphcore    = Dictionary<int,Children>
let directgraphcore  = new DFSgraphcore()
let reversegraphcore = new DFSgraphcore()

type DFSgraph1    = Dictionary<int,Node1>
let reversegraph1 = new DFSgraph1()

let AddtoGraph (G:DFSgraphcore) (n,c) = 
    if not(G.ContainsKey n) then 
                              let node = [c]
                              G.Add(n,node)
                            else
                               let c'= G.[n]
                               G.Remove(n) |> ignore
                               G.Add (n, List.append c' [c])

let inline swaptuple (a,b) = (b,a)
y|> Array.iter (AddtoGraph directgraphcore)
y|> Array.map swaptuple |> Array.iter (AddtoGraph reversegraphcore)

// définir reversegraph1 = ... with....
for i in reversegraphcore.Keys do
    let node = {children = reversegraphcore.[i] ;
                           finishingtime = -1 ;
                           explored1 = false ;
                           }
    reversegraph1.Add (i,node)

for i in directgraphcore.Keys do
    if not(reversegraphcore.ContainsKey(i)) then do                                 
               let node = {children = [] ;
                           finishingtime = -1 ;
                           explored1 = false ;
                           }
               reversegraph1.Add (i,node)

directgraphcore.Clear  |> ignore
reversegraphcore.Clear |> ignore

// for i in reversegraph1.Keys do printfn "%d %A" i reversegraph1.[i].children
printfn "pause"
Console.ReadKey() |> ignore

let num_nodes =
    directgraphcore |> Seq.length
```

So basically the graph is (1->2->3->1)::(4->5->6->7->8->....->99999->10000)
and the reverse graph is (1->3->2->1)::(10000->9999->....->4)

here is the main code written in direct style

```
//////////////////// main code is below ///////////////////

let DFSLoop1 (G:DFSgraph1)  = 
     let mutable t =  0 
     let mutable s =  -1

     let rec iter (n:int) (f:'a->unit) (list:'a list) : unit = 
         match list with 
            | [] -> (t <- t+1) ; (G.[n].finishingtime <- t)
            | x::xs -> f x ; iter n f xs      
     let rec DFSsub (G:DFSgraph1) (n:int) : unit =  
          let my_f (j:int) : unit = if not(G.[j].explored1) then (DFSsub G j) 
          G.[n].explored1 <- true         
          iter n my_f G.[n].children 

     for i in num_nodes .. -1 .. 1 do
        // printfn "%d" i
        if not(G.[i].explored1) then do 
                                    s <- i
                                    DFSsub G i                                                         

        printfn "%d %d" i G.[i].finishingtime

// End of DFSLoop1


DFSLoop1 reversegraph1

printfn "pause"
Console.ReadKey() |> ignore
```

its not tail recursive, so we use continuations, here is the same code adapted to CPS style:

```
//////////////////// main code is below ///////////////////
let DFSLoop1 (G:DFSgraph1)  = 
     let mutable t =  0 
     let mutable s =  -1

     let rec iter_c (n:int) (f_c:'a->(unit->'r)->'r) (list:'a list) (cont: unit->'r) : 'r = 
         match list with 
            | [] -> (t <- t+1) ; (G.[n].finishingtime <- t) ; cont()
            | x::xs -> f_c x (fun ()-> iter_c n f_c xs cont)
     let rec DFSsub (G:DFSgraph1) (n:int) (cont: unit->'r) : 'r=  
          let my_f_c (j:int)(cont:unit->'r):'r = if not(G.[j].explored1) then (DFSsub G j cont) else cont()
          G.[n].explored1 <- true         
          iter_c n my_f_c G.[n].children cont


     for i in maxnum_nodes .. -1 .. 1 do
       // printfn "%d" i
        if not(G.[i].explored1) then do 
                                    s <- i
                                    DFSsub G i id                                                         

        printfn "%d %d" i G.[i].finishingtime


DFSLoop1 reversegraph1
printfn "faré"
printfn "pause"
Console.ReadKey() |> ignore
```

both codes compile and give the same results for the small example (the one in comment) or the same tree that we are using , with a smaller size (1000 instead of 100000)

so i don't think its a bug in the algo here, we've got the same tree structure, just a bigger tree is causing problems. it looks to us the continuations are well written. we've typed the code explicitly. and all calls end with a continuation in all cases...

We are looking for expert advice !!! thanks !!!

Comment: Well, yes, you're not doing a tail call, so it can't be tail-call optimized. Your code is very imperative with a lot of mutable state, that's usually tricky to work with in a functional style.

Comment: @Luaan. sorry I am a beginner in programming...You mean its not (semi)obvious to transform a given recursive code into tail-recursive ?

Comment: i appreciate any ideas how to make the code more functional with less mutable variables, abandon global variables etc...

Comment: This is more of a [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) question than a specific problem question. You should start with simpler examples of a concept and work your way up to the harder ones.

Comment: I don't think you'll get an answer on SO - changing everything to functional is way out of scope for SO, and I'm not sure if there's anything simple you could do to make this work.

Comment: @Luaan if you could have a second look, that may be helpful. thanks

Comment: Looking at the generated IL bytecode could help you understand where exactly the problem occurs (basically, if there's anything between the last call and `ret`, that's what you need to get rid of). The function must return the result of the tail-called function directly. For the tail-recursive version, that is - I have no experience with using continuation passing to achieve a similar effect. The problem is that your code is both long *and* incomplete, so this is a bit of a guessing game for us :)

Comment: @Luaan all the code is there. I am trying to look at the IL bytecode. never done that ever before...i managed to run ildasm but struggling with it. I've read that there may be a problem with continuations when they are of type unit->'r because of the compiler being confused between unit and void. And also that if the compiler is in debug mode, then it may not deal with tail recursion properly. Is there a setting for that in VS ? i don't see it ? how can I check it ?

Comment: i posted the code (3 versions on Github). c is the direct version, d the continuation version, e the acc version. all run ok for small graph, but fail at a depth around 1500-2000 https://github.com/FaguiCurtain/Learning-Fsharp/tree/master/Algo%20Stanford%20I/Algo%20Stanford%20I

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so the code given above was the RIGHT code !
the problem lies with the compiler of F#

here is some words about it from Microsoft
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fsharpteam/archive/2011/07/08/tail-calls-in-fsharp.aspx

Basically, be careful with the settings, in default mode, the compiler may NOT make automatically the tail calls. To do so, in VS2015, go to the Solution Explorer, right click with the mouse and click on "Properties" (the last element of the scrolling list)
Then in the new window, click on "Build" and tick the box "Generate tail calls"

It is also to check if the compiler did its job looking at the disassembly using
ILDASM.exe

you can find the source code for the whole algo in my github repository

https://github.com/FaguiCurtain/Learning-Fsharp/blob/master/Algo%20Stanford/Algo%20Stanford/Kosaraju_cont.fs

on a performance point of view, i'm not very satisfied. The code runs on 36 seconds on my laptop. From the forum with other fellow MOOCers, C/C++/C# typically executes in subsecond to 5s, Java around 10-15, Python around 20-30s.
So my implementation is clearly not optimized. I am now happy to hear about tricks to make it faster !!! thanks !!!!

Answer (score 5):

I did not try to understand the whole code snippet, because it is fairly long, but you'll certainly need to replace the `for` loop with an iteration implemented using continuation passing style. Something like:

```
let rec iterc f cont list =
  match list with 
  | [] -> cont ()
  | x::xs -> f x (fun () -> iterc f cont xs)
```

I didn't understand the purpose of `cont` in your `DFSub` function (it is never called, is it?), but the continuation based version would look roughly like this:

```
let rec DFSsub (G:DFSgraph2)(n:int) cont =
  G.[n].explored2 <- true
  G.[n].leader <- s
  G.[n].children 
  |> iterc 
      (fun j cont -> if not(G.[j].explored2) then DFSsub G j cont else cont ()) 
      (fun () -> t <- t + 1)
```

Comment: is the for loop contributing to the overflow as well ?

Comment: Also, if the argument in let rec iterc f cont list is a MUTABLE variable, does it stil make sense, or we really must use an immutable type for the purpose of avoiding overflow ?

Comment: Hi; i've updated the code with continuations with the help of a lisper friend. He (we) think its semantically correct, but its still causing overflow... could you have a second look please ?

Answer (score 2):

Overflowing the stack when you recurse through hundreds of thousands of entries isn't bad at all, really. A lot of programming language implementations will choke on much shorter recursions than that. You're having serious programmer problems — nothing to be ashamed of!

Now if you want to do deeper recursions than your implementation will handle, you need to transform your algorithm so it is iterative and/or tail-recursive (the two are isomorphic — except that tail-recursion allows for decentralization and modularity, whereas iteration is centralized and non-modular).

To transform an algorithm from recursive to tail-recursive, which is an important skill to possess, you need to understand the state that is implicitly stored in a stack frame, i.e. those free variables in the function body that change across the recursion, and explicitly store them in a FIFO queue (a data structure that replicates your stack, and can be implemented trivially as a linked list). Then you can pass that linked list of reified frame variables as an argument to your tail recursive functions.

In more advanced cases where you have many tail recursive functions each with a different kind of frame, instead of simple self-recursion, you may need to define some mutually recursive data types for the reified stack frames, instead of using a list. But I believe Kosaraju's algorithm only involves self-recursive functions.